# Avoid Words getting cut in R

Tags: html, r, shiny

I use the below code to split the sentences into many parts, but I see some issue here, a single word is getting into second line which looks wierd on the front end. Can we avoid this?

```
library(shiny)
HTML(paste0(gsub("(.{10})", "\\1\n", "I saw a beautiful moon tonight")))
I saw a be
autiful mo
on tonight
```

Expected Output (This should be dynamic. So the code should self identify meaningful words)

```
I saw a 
beautiful
moon tonight
```

Comment: BTW, `paste0(gsub(..))` is overkill, `paste0` is doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in R function `strwrap`:

```r
strwrap("I saw a beautiful moon tonight", width=10)
# [1] "I saw a"   "beautiful" "moon"      "tonight"
```

Comment: Thanks, But how do I place in the next line (As mentioned in the question)?

Comment: @manup; ; `HTML(paste0(strwrap("I saw a beautiful moon tonight", width=10), collapse="\n"))` or `HTML(strwrap("I saw a beautiful moon tonight", width=10, prefix="\n", initial=""))`